# Meu listview esta sem clique

Tags: android

Não sei porque , mas os itens não clicam.

Meu layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/manager"
        android:background="#9b1136">
    </ImageView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"    
        android:id="@+id/lista"            
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>   

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.hide();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(DiretorioView.this, "teste", 1000).show();   

}
```

**Itens**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5sp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/lixo"
            android:text="Button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>         

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Debugou para saber se chega a passar no método `onItemClick` ?

Comment: nao chega la, joguei um log la e nada

Comment: War a edição ficou bem, era assim que queria por?

Comment: está otimo jorge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse problema ocorre quando você tem um item na sua lista que possui um foco, (seu `Button`) o que causa a não chamada o método `OnItemClickListener` ([veja esse bug reportado aqui](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414))

Isso não quer dizer que você não possa ter um botão dentro de uma lista, você pode utilizar (dependendo de sua necessidade):

1) Inserir o parametro `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` no pai de seu item na lista, e implementar o clique do botão normalmente em seu adapter, por exemplo:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...
            Button btn= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.youtButton);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ...
                }
            });
...
}
```

2) Colocar dentro da tag do seu `Button` o parametro `android:focusable="false"` e `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`

Comment: Deu certo colocando o item 2 no botao, porem ele ignorao botao, como tratar os dois? quer q eu poste meu adapter?

Comment: Remova o item 2, coloque `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` em seu item e defina o `OnClickListener` normalmente em seu adapter e tente novamente

Comment: quando eu coloco android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" no botao, nao clica

Comment: Não é no botão, é no pai do seu item. No seu caso, seu `LinearLayout`

Comment: pronto, e agora o tratamento do botao no adapter?

Comment: nao to entendendo muito como vou saber diferenciar , e seprar os cliques do botao e da lista

Comment: Editei minha resposta, deixei um pouco mais claro e com exemplo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20609/discussion-between-war-lock-and-sicachester).

Comment: Meu botao vai ser pra apagar um item da lista, como faço para pegar o item selecionado (string) la da lista e colocar no botao como o evento vai saber?